# how i can assign a specific link to every user by which i can visit his profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i want to assign a link for every user by which anyone can visit his profile i did this to achieve that hting but it doesn't work how i can do that

my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

from .views import SearchResultsView

# Template Urls!
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('Skolar/',views.base, name= 'base'),
    path('Register/',views.register,name='register'),
    path('login/', views.my_login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/',views.user_logout,name='logout'),
    path('<slug:username>/',views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('EditProfile/',views.update_profile,name='editprofile'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

my models.py for every user it created automatically with the help of signal

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User ,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',default='default.png',)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=80, blank=True,)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=80, blank=True,)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=1500, blank=True,)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

how i can assign that by which that link ony open that user profile which is assigned to it please help if you know how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you have a set of user's name displayed , pass the users details (here pk)into the urls parameter. see this example..

**views.py**

```
def userlist(request):
    list_user= Profile.objects.all()
    return render(request,'all_profiles.html',{'list_user':list_user})
```

this sends ths list of all users to the template using the context dictionary variable "list_user"

Now inject the recieved list of users in a HTML page :

**all_profiles.html**

```
{% for uprofile in list_user %}
    <a href="{% url 'profile' uprofile.id %}">{{uprofile.username}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

now you have a webpage that shows list of all available users and since it is in an anchor tag () and has href with profile/id it will send the corresponding "id" to the url.

example **"/profile/1"...**

now use the profile id passed with the url by ,

**urls.py**

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.profile, name = 'profile'),
```

here `<int:pk>` stores the id of the user coming from the template,

the id can be fetched in the views.py by,

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def profile(request,pk):
    user = get_user_model()
    user_profile = user.objects.get(pk = pk)

    return render(request,"profile.html", {'user_prof' : user_profile})
```

Now in the profile.html , you can inject any attribute of the User model.

**profile.html**

```
<h1>profile {{user_prof.username}} </h1>
    
<p>{{user_prof.email}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**In your url.py:**

```
path('my_profile/<int:pk>/', views.profile,name = 'my_profile'),
```

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def profile(request,pk):
    profile_data = Profile.objects.get(pk = pk)
    return render(request,'myprofile.html',{"profile_data":profile_data})

def allProfile(request):
    all_profile = Profile.objects.all()
    return render(request,'all_profile.html',{'all_profile':all_profile})
```

**all_profile.html:**

```
{% for pf in all_profile %}
......
    <a class="btn btn-sm" href="{% url 'my_profile' pf.id %}">{{pf.user_name}}</a>
......
{% endfor %}
```

This is link :

When user will click on this link he goes into their profile.

```
<a class="btn btn-sm" href="{% url 'my_profile' request.user.profile.id %}">My Profile </a>
```

Comment: Hello shreyash my code fully explained by @SANGEETH SUBRAMONIAM.Read below explaination of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the Profile model linked up to the inbuilt User model by a foreign key, you can just build a HTML page and inject the current users into the template tags.

**For visiting any other users profile,**

pass the username of the profile you want to see as url parameter. Receive the parameter in the views.py,

**views.py**

```
> def profile (request, username): 
>     user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

now send the user through the Context dictionary and render the required details in your template.

Comment: showing error NameError at /shreyash/

name 'User' is not defined